# Change rotation axis in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuW0B.png)there is a task to rotate the cube, but during rotation the axis of rotation is in the center how to shift it to the side

```
 let skyboxGeo3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 250, 10,250 );
 let skybox3 = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeo3, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } ) );
 skybox3.rotation.y= 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let root = new THREE.Object3D()
scene.add(root)
root.add(cube)
cube.position.x += 128
root.rotation.y = 10
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuW0B.png like this, how change axis rotation

Comment: I showed one way ^

Here's another way...

cube.geometry.translate(0,0,250);